# selenium webdriver - headless chrome error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

I am working on webscraping using webdriver in python and getting this error even with the updated webdriver. Could anyone help me in this regard.

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
(Session info: headless chrome=86.0.4240.111)

Comment: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED is a DNS error when it can't resolve an IP for a website.